# How do I add two vectors created by a class to eachother?

Tags: python, class, math

I have to add vector b to vector a. My class looks like this:

```
class Vector:
    """
    creates a vector, which can be indexed, changed and added to another vector.
    """
    def __init__(self,n=0,vec=[]):
        """
        creating vecor
        """
        self.n=n
        self.vec=list(vec)
        if len(vec)==0:
            for i in range(n):
                self.vec.append(0)
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        """
        indexing
        """
        if i>=len(self.vec):
            return(None)
        else:
            return(self.vec[i])
    def __setitem__(self,i,val):
        """
        changing
        """
        self.vec[i]=val
```

I tried adding another method to my class called add:

```
def add(a,b):
        """
        adds vector b to a
        """
        x=0
        for i in b:
            a[x]=a[x]+i
            x+=1
        return (a)
```

Lets say I want this to work:
a = Vector(vec = [1, 2, 3])
b = Vector(vec = [3, 4, 5])

c = Vector.add(a, b)

Comment: What should vector `c` look like after `a = Vector(vec = [1, 2, 3]) b = Vector(vec = [3, 4, 5]) c = Vector.add(a, b)`

Comment: Also why not make `add` a dunder method? `__add__` so you can do: `c = a + b`

Comment: The vector c would look like this: c=[4,6,8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you're trying to do make a classmethod.

Something like this should work:

```
@classmethod
def add(cls, a,b):
    """
    adds vector b to a
    """
    return cls(vec=[x + y for x, y in zip(a.vec, b.vec)])
```